# Styling WordPress Custom Nav Menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, menu

I created a custom menu for globalgolflinks.com:

in functions.php:

```
`register_nav_menu('page_title_nav', 'Page Title Navigation');
```

and I placed it in header.php:

```
'<?php wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'page-nav', 'container_id' => 'flag-nav', 'theme_location' => 'page_title_nav' ) ); ?>
```

However I can't figure out how to make it have the same style as the rest of the theme. I also want to place a flag before item and so far all I've been able to do is place a flag as a background, but it doesn't display fully because the area is too small.

I would very much appreciate any help you could give.

Thank you!

Comment: Check what the class name for the  other menu's? and make this one the same 'container_class' => 'the-class-name'.

Comment: okay I changed the class to nav-holder, but it's still not taking any of the styling. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

first of all change your class of menu

change in css ![enter image description here][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbrxN.png
change ul color to white
ui border none
font size 15 px